# How to extract information from multiple if given multiple table and multiple row

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Give the HTML code below as an example

```
<table class="A">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="A">
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Using the code as an example, how do I traverse through the `table` and `td` to get the data `D`

Above is just the example of HTML code. All I can think of to traverse is using `Iterator <Element>` but I'm given an error

Below is my code.

```
Iterator <Element> ele = doc.select("table.borderwrap").iterator();

System.out.println(ele.next().text());
System.out.println(ele.next().text());
System.out.println(ele.next().text());
System.out.println(ele.next().text());

Iterator <Element> ele2 = ele.select("td[class=row1]").iterator();
```

On the last line of my given code, the part `select` gives me error which I don't know why.

Comment: @benjamin.d Frankly speaking, I don't know either what is the error. Netbeans underline the part in red proves it is error but when I check, it doesn't show what is the error but gives the option to split the declaration. Sorry because I'm new to JSoup.

Comment: Do you mean netbeans indicates a compilation issue? Or do you get an exception in your netbeans console ?

Comment: @benjamin.d Netbeans indicate a compilation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your last line you are calling the `select` method on an `Iterator`.

Maybe what you meant is:

```
Iterator <Element> ele2 = ele.**next()**.select("td[class=row1]").iterator();
```